# how to access php.ini and set file_upload directive to "on"

Tags: php, image-upload

I am working on my school project which we use Winscp as a server.
So im new to php trying to work on image upload and I have read many articles saying I need to edit my php.ini file and set file_uploads directive to "on". But I just do not know where my php.ini file is at.

Here is my link to my phpinfo.php: http://cgi.sice.indiana.edu/~baehy/phpinfo.php
So it says my php.ini is at /etc/php.ini and I cannot find it on my computer(i know it may sound silly)

Every comment is appreciated! Thank you all in advance!

Here is my code

```
<?php 
  session_start();
include('database.php');
ini_set('max_exection_time', 60);
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
header('location: http://cgi.sice.indiana.edu/~baehy/team72index.php');
} else {
echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['userid'] . "<br>";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$title = $_POST['title'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
//get file from the form and get following information
$file = $_FILES['coverimage'];
$fileName = $_FILES['coverimage']['name'];
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['coverimage']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['coverimage']['size'];
$fileError = $_FILES['coverimage']['error'];
$fileType = $_FILES['coverimage']['type'];

//retrieve file extention using explode()
$fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
//because some file extentions might be in capital letters
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png');
if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
  if($fileError === 0){
    //if the size of the file is lesser than 1M kb = 1000mb
    if($fileSize < 1000000){
      $fileNameNew = uniqid('',true).".".$fileActualExt;
      chmod('uploads/',0777);
      echo "permission granted to uploads directory!" . "<br>";
      $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
      move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
      echo $fileNameNew . "<br>";
      echo "Successfully uploaded your file" . "<br>";
    } else {
      echo "Your file is too big to upload" . "<br>";
    }
  } else {
    echo "There was an error uploading your file" . "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "This file extention is not allowed to be uploaded" . "<br>";
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO `recipe` (title, category, description, coverimage, userid)
VALUES ('".$title."', '".$category."', '".$description."', '".$fileName."', '".$_SESSION['userid']."')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if($result){
  echo "successfully added to database";
} else {
  echo "failed to add to database";
}
$showImage = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `coverimage` FROM `recipe`");
}
}
```

p.s. and also do I need to put the absolute path of the folder('uploads') to use it in the code? Thank you!

Comment: WinSCP is FTP client, isn't it?

Comment: The `php.ini` file is probably protected on the server, and you will most likely (if the server is set up *correctly*) not be able to access it without the correct permissions.  In addition, even using the `ini_set` as in @Daniels answer .. You'll still have to have permissions to set this within the program itself.

Comment: Doing upload on localhost on windows, let alone another OS is going to be challenging. One key factor is ensuring folder permissions are correct and that any application (node, winscp, mamp, docker) is able to put files where you need it to on your system. I'd point you towards [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) for IT-advice that's outside of programming

Comment: What messages do you get when you try to upload your file? Do you know +- where it fails? BTW: Please add at least escaping using `mysqli_real_escape_string`, your code is very unsafe.

Comment: Instead of absolute path, you can use __DIR__ constant, which is string with absolute path to current directory. So e.g. `__DIR__ . '/uploads/' . $newImageName;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php.ini is system file located at remote web server and it contains global configuration for PHP. Only privileged users can edit php.ini.

You can change local configuration for your script using function `ini_set`, for example:

```
ini_set('max_exection_time', 60);
```

According to `phpinfo()` you sent, you already have `file_uploads` set to On. So you don't need to edit anything. Just open link you sent, press CTRL+F and search for `file_uploads`.

---

By the way, WinSCP is only application used to transfer files to remote web server using FTP/SFTP or similar protocols. Actually your web server is running on RHEL Apache 2.4.6. Just see section `SERVER_SOFTWARE` in your phpinfo.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! But its still not uploading my image to the designated directory :(((

Answer (score 0):

Using WinSCP, connect to remote server. Go to remote server's root directory and then go to `/etc/php.ini`.

It won't be on your computer, it's on the remote server. The server is running on Apache. You are using Winscp as a FTP software to access the files of remote server.

Learn how to use WinSCP - https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/winscp/